# Rename file ( what ever name ) on sub folder by using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder which contains one text file
I could use the below code to rename it successfully.
**Problem** If the initial name of that file is changed, an error raised `File not found`.
So,I need to rename that file ( what ever name ) on sub folder `(Desktop)` by using VBA.
In advance, appreciate for any help.

```
Sub Rename_File()

    Dim oldName As String
    Dim newName As String
    oldName = "C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\Test.txt"
    newName = "C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\work.txt"
    Name oldName As newName
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Dir("C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\*")` to find the name of the file

Comment: @Tim Williams I used `oldName =Dir("C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\*")` but the same error

Comment: Dir() only returns the file *name* not the full path.  You need to add the path to that name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code, assumption is there is **only one** file in the directory

```
Sub Rename_File()

    Const pathName = "D:\TMP\01"  `<= Change accordingly
    
    Dim oldName As String
    Dim newName As String
    
    oldName = Dir(pathName & Application.PathSeparator & "*.*")
    oldName = pathName & Application.PathSeparator & oldName
    
    newName = pathName & Application.PathSeparator & "work.txt"
    
    Name oldName As newName
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Works excellent 